# React - Browser stops updating element when state is a string, works when state is an array

Tags: reactjs

[image]

The context of this code is a typewriter effect. I am updating the state letter by letter, which gets rendered in a span element. When I concatenate the letters to a string, it works at first but after a few seconds the browser stops updating the element. It waits until all the updates are done, and then updates the text again one last time. If I add all the letters to an array, the browser updates the element correctly. However, when I inspect the element I can see that the DOM is correctly updating.

To make the problem a bit clearer, here's a [gif of the browser animating the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4w4B.jpg)

Here is a working version, which replicates the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/jj8zym92q5

```
class Typewriter extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            display: ''
        }
    }

    async type() {
        const typeLetter = (letter) =>
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 70, letter))
                .then(letter => this.setState({ display: this.state.display + letter }))

        for (const letter of this.props.text) {
            await typeLetter(letter)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.type()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span>{this.state.display}</span>
        )
    }
}

export default Typewriter;
```

CSS (Using Sass)

```
.typewriter {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 600;
    &:after {
        content: '_';
        animation: blink_underline 1s step-end infinite;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    &.typing {
        &:after {
            animation: none;
        }
    }
}
@keyframes blink_underline {
    from, to { opacity: 0 }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting issue, could you try using the CSS `transform: translateZ(0);` "hack" on the element?

Comment: Haven't heard of that hack. But I tried it, and it didn't work.

Comment: I found out that removing the cursor, which is just a pseudo-element and content '_', helped the freeze effect. But the browser behavior is still not clear to me. The animation is also not as smooth as with an array as a state.

Comment: Could you set a working jsFiddle or codepen to better see what is going on?

Comment: Good idea. Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jj8zym92q5

Comment: [This react discussion](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/repaint-bug-markup-exists-but-not-being-shown/558) sounds exactly like my problem. Sadly, no good solution there either.

Comment: Im having difficulty with the sandbox, it takes much time every time it needs to update. However, try this simple thing, add CSS `display:block;` to the span inside the p. This breaks the `:after` following the last letter though, so test with the different `display` values.

Comment: I had the same issue, not sure why. Which browser are you using? When I used chrome it worked a lot better than in Safari. I tried that, unfortunately it did not work. I found a hacky solution, but I don't think I should post it here. Maybe someone will find the reason for this bug and a real solution.

Comment: Im using Chrome, I put it in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx8pd3bq/), which seems to work better. Are you sure? It seems to work for me, please check the Fiddle.

Comment: Well it seems like you changed the CSS, in your fiddle the blinking cursor is in a different line that the letters.